# Chrome Version 66 : Blocked current origin from receiving cross-site document at

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On my local machine i have been using --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
to disable the web security. After upgrading to Chrome Version 66 i have started getting  Blocked current origin from receiving cross-site document at ... warning. How to disable the web security for this version of chrome ?

Answer (score 11):

Found a workaround mentioned in https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --disable-web-securi
ty --user-data-dir --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating
```

Comment: This only seems to work if I also opt out of the following setting chrome://flags/#site-isolation-trial-opt-out But I cannot find a command-line equivalent option for this. Any ideas? Using v66.0.3359.170 of chrome.

Comment: This workaround worked for me with Chrome 66.0.3359.139

Comment: Same problem as @Glenn with `66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: Works with `70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This has apparently been fixed in Chrome 67. You can find the bug I reported and a workaround [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=842040). The command-line workaround requires you to start Chrome with the following argument:

`--disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add

`--disable-site-isolation-trials`

This works in Chrome 68.