# Blocked current origin from receiving cross-site document at 'myRemoteSite' with MIME type application/json

Tags: google-chrome, types, mime, cross-site

I think happened in the latest update of Chrome. They're not letting any of these content types if they come from a site. This is problematic because I need the chrome developer tools to develop my app making calls to an api. Does anyone know how to disable or override this?

Comment: same here. i m getting the same problem

Comment: Found a fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146938/chrome-version-66-blocked-current-origin-from-receiving-cross-site-document-at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the directory in cmd to "cd Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
   and execute the below command to disable chrome security and also avoid "Blocked receiving cross-site document warning."
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating

Comment: The --disable-features flag doesn't seem to be working anymore.  Any idea why?