# How can i unblock cors via chrome webrequest api

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to unblock cors in all requests that occurs in [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) via xhr for example in it i request to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) how can i add response headers for it like Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

```
    
var corsorg = {
        name: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        value: "https://www.example.com"
      };
     var corstrue = {
        name: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
        value: "true"
      };
      e.responseHeaders.push(corsorg);
      e.responseHeaders.push(corstrue);
     console.log(e);
 },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
);
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to make the request in the background script and send the result back, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292071).

Comment: i want to catch all response header requests and change it

Comment: Then try adding `"extraHeaders"` in the last array.

Comment: it's only works for www.example.com/* but not working static.exaple.com/*.js and other subdomains

Comment: Probably because you specify www.example.com in your code.