# Manifest V3 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, google-api, service-worker, manifest

Hi my chrome extension just updated to Manifest V3 and I'm encountering a problem when posting data to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`

here's my code:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  action: "post_request", 
  url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', 
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  params: `code=${authorizationCode}&client_id=${dbClientId}&client_secret=&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&grant_type=authorization_code` },
  async function(_response) {
    let response = JSON.parse(_response.data);
    if (response.access_token) {
      response.success = true
      const idTokenDetails = await getIdTokenInfo(response.id_token);
      // Set expire time for token and save in Chrome Storage
      response.expiresAt = nowInSeconds + response.expires_in
      response.idTokenDetails = idTokenDetails;
      //save in storage
      UserInfoStorage.setGoogleIdToken(idTokenDetails)
      UserInfoStorage.setGoogleAccessToken(response);
      callback(response)
    }
    else {
      response.success = false;
      callback(response);
    }
  }
)
```

and getting the error in my console:

[image: Error]

this is my code on the background:

```
if(request.action === 'post_request') {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', request.url, true);
  if(request.headers) {
    for(let header in request.headers) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(header, request.headers[header]);
    }
  }
  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.response) {
      sendResponse({success:true, data:xhr.response})
    } else {
      sendResponse({success:false, statusText:xhr.statusText})
    }
  };
  if(request.params) {
    xhr.send(request.params)
  }
  else {
    xhr.send();
  }
}
```

can somebody help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: The error is saying that your onMessage in the background script returns `undefined`. Show the code of your onMessage.

Comment: Looks like it's missing `return true`, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292071).

Comment: it has, at the bottom part

Comment: Well, I guess it doesn't run then. Use devtools to set breakpoints and debug your code. Maybe the request takes more than 30 seconds to complete? In that case ManifestV3 will terminate the background script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALRIGHT! this is solved by Replacing `XMLHttpRequest` into `fetch()` and `request.action` to `request.contentScriptQuery`