# Whitelist all domains for a google chrome extension built with react js using firebase authentification

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a google chrome extension using react js . Withing my app i'm using firebase authentification service. I created a button so that the user can authentificate with twitter .
This is the button code.

```
 onClick={() => {
              firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider())
```

So when the user click on the button , a popup appears and firebase authentificate the user.
When i load the extension to chrome and run it , it runs correctly but when i click on the button i get this error :

```
content.js:37916 Uncaught xh {code: "auth/unauthorized-domain", message: "This domain (meet.google.com) is not authorized to…se console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.", a: null}
```

It seems that i should whitelist every singe web page(url), in firebase console ,that the the user is launching the extension from .
Is there a solution?

Comment: Content scripts can't make cross-origin requests, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292071).

Comment: so there is no solution for this ?