# How do I make this Request API work with CORS?

Tags: javascript, rest, google-chrome-extension, request

Thanks for reading.
I'm making a Spoiler Blocker Chrome Extension, and as you can imagine that's been quite a journey...
Right now I have everything sorted out, except the last part. Because of CORS Policy, I have to use a middleman (Cloudflare worker) to access the Razor API from the extension (returns data about entities).
I found an open source code from managing requests with Cors activated for the Cloudflare worker, but it's been days, and I can't get it to send requests as I want it to. I tried predetermining the url to analyze and other stuff, but it just doesn't work.

´´´

The API: https://www.textrazor.com/docs/rest

```
fetch('https://secret.workers.dev/?https://api.textrazor.com', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'extractors': 'entities,sentences',
                'text': txt
            }),
            headers: {
                'x-cors-headers': JSON.stringify({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'X-TextRazor-Key': 'secret',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
                })
            }
```

Cloudflare worker code:

````
 addEventListener("fetch", async event=>{
    event.respondWith((async function() {
        isOPTIONS = (event.request.method == "OPTIONS");
        var origin_url = new URL(event.request.url); ```

        function fix(myHeaders) {
            //            myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", event.request.headers.get("Origin"));
            if (isOPTIONS) {
                myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", event.request.headers.get("access-control-request-method"));
                acrh = event.request.headers.get("access-control-request-headers");
                //myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

                if (acrh) {
                    myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", acrh);
                }

                myHeaders.delete("X-Content-Type-Options");
            }
            return myHeaders;
        }
        var fetch_url = decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(origin_url.search.substr(1)));

        var orig = event.request.headers.get("Origin");
        
        var body = event.request;
        
        var remIp = event.request.headers.get("CF-Connecting-IP");

        if ((!isListed(fetch_url, blacklist)) && (isListed(orig, whitelist))) {

            xheaders = event.request.headers.get("x-cors-headers");

            if (xheaders != null) {
                try {
                    xheaders = JSON.parse(xheaders);
                } catch (e) {}
            }

            if (origin_url.search.startsWith("?")) {
                recv_headers = {};
                for (var pair of event.request.headers.entries()) {
                    if ((pair[0].match("^origin") == null) && (pair[0].match("eferer") == null) && (pair[0].match("^cf-") == null) && (pair[0].match("^x-forw") == null) && (pair[0].match("^x-cors-headers") == null)) {
                        recv_headers[pair[0]] = pair[1];
                    }
                }
            
                if (xheaders != null) {
                    Object.entries(xheaders).forEach((c)=>recv_headers[c[0]] = c[1]);
                }

                var myHeaders = new Headers();
                myHeaders.append('x-textrazor-key', 'secret');
                myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

                var myBody = {
                    extractors: 'entities,sentences',
                    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marty_McFly'
                }
                
                newreq = new Request("https://api.textrazor.com", {

                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: myHeaders,
                    body: myBody

                })

                var response = await fetch(fetch_url,newreq);
                var myHeaders = new Headers(response.headers);
                cors_headers = [];
                allh = {};
                for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) {
                    cors_headers.push(pair[0]);
                    allh[pair[0]] = pair[1];
                }
                cors_headers.push("cors-received-headers");
                myHeaders = fix(myHeaders);

                myHeaders.set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", cors_headers.join(","));

                myHeaders.set("cors-received-headers", JSON.stringify(allh));

                if (isOPTIONS) {
                    var body = null;
                } else {
                    var body = await response.arrayBuffer();
                }

                var init = {
                    headers: myHeaders,
                    status: (isOPTIONS ? 200 : response.status),
                    statusText: (isOPTIONS ? "OK" : response.statusText)
                };
                return new Response(body,init);

            } else {
                var myHeaders = new Headers();
                myHeaders = fix(myHeaders);

                if (typeof event.request.cf != "undefined") {
                    if (typeof event.request.cf.country != "undefined") {
                        country = event.request.cf.country;
                    } else
                        country = false;

                    if (typeof event.request.cf.colo != "undefined") {
                        colo = event.request.cf.colo;
                    } else
                        colo = false;
                } else {
                    country = false;
                    colo = false;
                }

                return new Response(
                    "CLOUDFLARE-CORS-ANYWHERE\n\n" + 
                    "Source:\nhttps://github.com/Zibri/cloudflare-cors-anywhere\n\n" + 
                    "Usage:\n" + origin_url.origin + "/?uri\n\n" +
            "Donate:\nhttps://paypal.me/Zibri/5\n\n" +
                    "Limits: 100,000 requests/day\n" + 
                    "          1,000 requests/10 minutes\n\n" + 
                    (orig != null ? "Origin: " + orig + "\n" : "") + 
                    "Ip: " + remIp + "\n" + 
                    (country ? "Country: " + country + "\n" : "") + 
                    (colo ? "Datacenter: " + colo + "\n" : "") + "\n" + 
                    ((xheaders != null) ? "\nx-cors-headers: " + JSON.stringify(xheaders) : ""),
                    {status: 200, headers: myHeaders}
                );
            }
        } else {

            return new Response(
                "Create your own cors proxy</br>\n" + 
                "<a href='https://github.com/Zibri/cloudflare-cors-anywhere'>https://github.com/Zibri/cloudflare-cors-anywhere</a></br>\n" +
                "\nDonate</br>\n" +
                "<a href='https://paypal.me/Zibri/5'>https://paypal.me/Zibri/5</a>\n",
                {
                    status: 403,
                    statusText: 'Forbidden',
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "text/html"
                    }
                });
        }
    }
    )());
    });
````

Error: "Please specify a TextRazor request."

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

So, I tried doing the background thingy. But... it doesn't work
background.js after receiving the message from content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, value, request, sendResponse) {

if (msg.from == "content") {  //get content scripts tab id

contentTabId = sender.tab.id;

var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("x-textrazor-key", "secret");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("text", request.txt);
urlencoded.append("extractors", "entities,entailments");

fetch("https://api.textrazor.com/", {

  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'

}).then((response) => sendResponse(response.json()));

return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.

}
```

content.js after receiving the first message from background (that orders it to look up the text from the page the user is on)

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            contentScriptQuery: "querySpoiler", txt: txt, messsage: { from: "content" }, responseCallback: function (response) {
                request = response.json();
```

When looking onto it in DevTools, runtime.sendMessage arguments and caller return an error:
TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
at Function.r (:1:83)
at chrome-extension://gbbiidobmakfdibhklcfnadmobpekifb/content.js:61:15

Thanks again!

Comment: Show us where and how each posted fragment of code runs. If the first one is a content script, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292071).

Comment: Hi. Your idea was pretty good, but I can't seem to get it quite right. Can you check the edit? @wOxxOm

Comment: Your adaptation is incorrect in both scripts. You can use the code in linked answer as is (mostly), just remove parsePrice line and add JSON.parse() in the content script. Also pay attention where the callback is defined: there's no such thing as responseCallback property, it's just a positional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To make cross-domain requests in an extension, list all hosts you need to access in the extension manifest.

- In manifest v3 the key is `"host_permissions"` ​(in manifest v2 it is `"permissions"`)
- The value will be an array of 1 or more match patterns

The example in original post shows the target host is `https://api.textrazor.com`. The extension manifest should include the following permission. After adding the permission, and within the extension context, it will be allowed to make requests to the specified host without needing a proxy server.

```json
{
  "host_permissions": [ 
    "https://api.textrazor.com/*"
  ]
}
```

The `*` represents a wildcard and means: "match any path that starts with this pattern". You can change the match pattern based on your requirements to include different schemes, subdomains, paths, etc. and add more entries to the value to include more hosts in general. See: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns for more details and examples of how to define match patterns.

After that, you can perform the API requests, example:

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("x-textrazor-key", "API_KEY_HERE");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("text", "Spain's stricken Bankia expects to sell off its vast portfolio of industrial holdings that includes a stake in the parent company of British Airways and Iberia.");
urlencoded.append("extractors", "entities,entailments");


fetch("https://api.textrazor.com/", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
})
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: You're the best, I'll try it out and let you know if I succeed! Thanks, seriously

Comment: Hi. Your idea was pretty good, but I can't seem to get it quite right. Can you check the edit?

Comment: Message passing between content and background is a different topic. I suggest, first try to perform the request in the background when the extension loads to debug and to make sure you are able to perform a request successfully. Second add the message passing.