# Run a Apps Script from Chrome Extension

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-chrome-extension

So I got a working Chrome Extension that listens for clicks on a webpage and when one of the correct buttons is clicked, logs some text.
Now, instead of logging the text, I want to call a Apps Script function that writes the text to a Google Spreadsheet.

My problem now is I really dont understand the whole authentication process.
I tried following this tutorial: https://hawksey.info/blog/2017/05/using-the-google-apps-script-execution-api-in-chrome-extensions/

But all I get are cors- or 401-errors.

The Chrome Extension manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "test",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "Munrador",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "identity"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://myWebsite"
            ],
            "js": [
                "script.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "",
        "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
        ]
    },
    "key": ""
}
```

script.js:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', async e => {
    if (e.target.className === 'fa-solid fa-circle-plus') {
        const script_id = '';
        let text = e.path[4].children[2].children[0].innerText;

        console.log(text);

        await fetch('https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/' + script_id + ':run', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ function: 'test', parameters: [text], devMode: true })
        });
    }
});
```

I hope someone has done something similar and can help me with this.

Comment: Do it in the background script, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292071/).

Comment: @wOxxOm Well this fixed the erros but the function still doesnt get executet

Comment: Go look at the example wOxxOm linked you, you have to send a message from the content script to the background script on the click of the button.

Comment: @MunraX If your goal is to populate a spreadsheet, why not call the Sheet API directly instead of going through Apps Script as an intermediary?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page about it: https://hawksey.info/blog/2017/05/using-the-google-apps-script-execution-api-in-chrome-extensions/

It seems you need to deploy as an API executable and do all this stuff in GCP. It *is* on an older version but not much has changed.

Instead of pressing publish you want the deploy button up the top

[image: Screenshot shows publish menu in old apps script]