# How is instagram.com web-version able to ignore its CORS when requesting to i.instagram.com?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cors, instagram, fetch-api

I'm trying to finish up a simple browser extension. It'll do some stuff at instagram.com, that is, at the web version.

I haven't succeeded in making requests to `i.instagram.com` due to CORS restrictions. Whereas instagram itself, from the browser, is always able to make the same types of requests (Ajax). How?

Whereas my browser extension, doing seemingly the same request, in the same manner -- not.

```
//fetch("https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/{some_api_point}", {
fetch("https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/{some_api_point}", {

    method: 'POST',
    redirect: 'follow',      //!
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',  //!
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Alt-Used': 'i.instagram.com',
        'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
        'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com',
        'Sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'Sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',


        'x-asbd-id': '<...>',
        'x-csrftoken': '<...>',
        'x-ig-app-id': '<...>',
        'x-ig-www-claim': '<hardcoded>',
        'x-instagram-ajax': '<...>',
    }
```

Another thing -- I replayed some of the made requests of Instagram in Firefox via DevTool and they also worked. That is,  I'd send requests  to `i.instagram.com` and receive responses in JSON with no problem, no error.

What's the matter? How's the browser able to send ajax request to `i.instagram.com` insite  CORS restrictions, but my extension, via `fetch`, **from the same browser** and same page - not?

P.S.

I think that I send along the correct headers. I also include cookies (`credentials: 'include'`)

[browser and instagram #1 (the 1st 'create' is called by my extension)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yFAU.png)

[browser and instagram #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD70K.png)

[extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gqWf.png)

---

More specifically, when I send a request to `www.instagram.com/api/...` it won't fail, but it won't return any data either:

> Failed to load response data: No content available because this request was redirected

Comment: If you make it in the content script, I guess the problem is that POST requests are restricted there intentionally, so you'll need to make it in the background script, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292071/).

Comment: @wOxxOm even if that's the case,  Instagram still has CORS policy, therefore nobody at `www.instagram.com` is allowed to make requests to `i.instagram.com`. Nonetheless, somehow Instagram's website makes them. How?

Comment: Instagram's CSP allows this host. Content scripts are special, they aren't allowed to make cross-origin POST requests. Use the workaround I linked.

Comment: @wOxxOm then how would I be able to use cookie, or `with credentials` in a background script?

Comment: It'll be added automatically.

Comment: @wOxxOm yesterday, in my other question, you said that for cookies to get added automatically, I'd have to use content script. Now it's automatically with background script. Where is it non-automatical then?

Comment: I can't remember what you did yesterday... Cookie behavior depends on various things.

Comment: @wOxxOm what I did yesterday was the very same thing we're talking about here

Answer (score 0):

**< Chrome 73**

In your `manifest.json` file, add

```
"permissions": [
    "*://*.instagram.com/*"
],
```

This will allow CORS with Instagram.

---

**Chrome 73+**

CORS is not allowed in newer versions of chrome, even after adding the `permissions` array. However, CORS is allowed in background scripts.

Therefore, add background scripts to the `manifest.json` file

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["backgroundTasks.js"],
  "persistent": false
}
```

In your `background.js` file, add

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(url, sender, onSuccess) {
        fetch("https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/{some_api_point}", {

    method: 'POST',
    redirect: 'follow',      //!
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',  //!
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Alt-Used': 'i.instagram.com',
        'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
        'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com',
        'Sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'Sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',


        'x-asbd-id': '<...>',
        'x-csrftoken': '<...>',
        'x-ig-app-id': '<...>',
        'x-ig-www-claim': '<hardcoded>',
        'x-instagram-ajax': '<...>',
    })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(responseText => onSuccess(responseText))
        
        return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.
    }
);
```

and finally, in your `main.js` file, add

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      'https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/{some_api_point}',
      data => (data) { //use your data here }
);
```