# How to fix CORS when request is coming from Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, express, google-chrome-extension, cors

I am writing a Chrome Extension that needs to make a call to my server.  I am getting

> Access to fetch at (server-website) from origin 'chrome-extension://abc' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

However I have my express js server setup to handle CORS from the chrome extension

```
var cors = require("cors");
var corsOptions = {
  origin: [
    "server-url",
    "chrome-extension://abc",
  ],
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions), express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: See also [How to make a cross-origin request in a content script (currently blocked by CORB despite the correct CORS headers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292071)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add server url to host_permissions in extansion manifest.

As far as I know, browsers block requests to other websites to protect user privacy. See more on manifest documentation: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/host_permissions)